# How to add a card next to icon on click like a dialog in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

[image]

There exist cards & existing UI in background.
On click of icon, I want to add this card kind of layout which has custom shape. Right side of the card has a arrow pointing to icon. How can I achieve this in compose
And on click of icon again or anywhere outside the card, it should vanish

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Popup** controll. By default, the Popup will be shown in alignment with the Top-Left of the parent container. Short example with offset:

```
var isPopupVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Button(onClick = { isPopupVisible = true }) {
    Text("Show Popup")
}

if (isPopupVisible) {
    val offsetX = 0.dp
    val offsetY = 50.dp

    Popup(
        alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
        offset = IntOffset(offsetX.roundToPx(), offsetY.roundToPx())
    ) {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

triangle

```
@Composable
fun Triangle(
    color: Color,
    height: Dp,
    width: Dp
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width, height)
            .background(color)
            .transform(
                // Rotate the box by 45 degrees
                rotationZ = 45f
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: How can I position it based on the card that is behind. Also how can I add a right triangle which points to the icon

Comment: I texted **By default, the Popup will be shown in alignment with the Top-Left of the parent container."** and you can corrcet by means of offsetX and offsetY. triangle you can add as compose function. Added code

Comment: Can you share roundToPx() Also I can add PopUp and put a background to it. But how do I add the icon on right such that the centre height of box & triangle tip are at start of icon